# how to generate playwright report of web vitals performance checks for different network conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, playwright, playwright-test

I want to generate a playwright report for one of the test cases for **slow 3g and other different network conditions** but as a result, I need the **FCP**,**LCP**, and other metric results in HTML Report to be generated which I am not able to achieve it.

```
test('network throttling', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
  const client = await page.context().newCDPSession(page);
  await client.send('Network.enable');
  await client.send('Network.emulateNetworkConditions', {
    offline: false,
    downloadThroughput: (0.4 * 1024 * 1024) / 8,
    uploadThroughput: (0.4 * 1024 * 1024) / 8,
    latency: 2000,
  });
});
```